# HTML5 Custom controls not visible in fullscreen on Mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, css, html, firefox

Im Trying to create custom controls for HTML5 Video player.
In Google Chrome's Fullscreen mode the custom controls are visible.
But
In Mozilla firefox the controls are hidden behind the fullscreen wrapper.
I have tried all the technique of giving z-index higher than 2147483647 and all, but nothing helped.

Can somebody please help me by providing a better solution?
Here is my HTML

```
<div class="video_container">
    <video width="400" height="225" poster="">
        <source src="introSnaphots.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="player" style="width: 95%; left: 2.5%;">
            <div class="play-pause play">
                <div class="play-button glyphicon glyphicon-play"></div>
                <div class="pause-button glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="v_progress">
                <div class="v_progress-bar" style="width: 0px;">
                    <div class="button-holder">
                        <div class="v_progress-button" style="left: -14px;"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="time">
                    <span class="ctime"></span>
                    <span class="stime"></span>
                    <span class="ttime"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="buffered" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="volume">
                <div class="volume-holder">
                    <div class="volume-bar-holder">
                        <div class="volume-bar">
                            <div class="volume-button-holder">
                                <div class="volume-button"> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="volume-icon v-change-0">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fullscreen"> 
                <a href="#" class="FullscreenOff">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please refer to "How to ask"

Comment: Do you plan to share the relevant source code or do you expect people to create a custom HTML5 player to find a fix for your problem? Nothing to work with = no solutions given.

Comment: @NewToJS well actually we could advice OP to transfer the video's fullscreen request to the container element since this is obviously the source of the problem (i.e create a custom fullscreen button in the custom controls)

Comment: I have the complete code. Im just looking for the only solution for Mozilla.

Comment: @Kaiido That would be a solution but if you read "providing a better solution" I'm sure the OP would like multiple solutions if people are able to come up with them but without the current source code that means those who wish the help will have to create the player before being able to find another solution. It isn't hard to add the relevant source code.

Comment: @NewToJS I do agree OP didn't respected his parts of the contract (especially the [mcve] one) so I won't anwer it, but I disagree with the "Nothing to work with = no solutions given" part of your comment. The description of the problem is enough for anyone with enough knowledge to identify the problem (fullscreen API implementation is a nightmare, this issue is well known)

Comment: @RanjanKaliya I'm sure you also have some javascript in here for us...

Comment: @RanjanKaliya and some CSS unless you want all those div elements in the wrong place. I would also include `glyphicon` otherwise the divs will be empty making it impossible to find/see them.

Comment: @Kaiido, NewToJS...thankyou for following up. The JS code I have is too big to share here. But I will share the URL once I host it running demo.
Mean while can you please give me a solution to go fullscreen video in IE-11. Thankyou very much.